# Issue with 24 hour time parameter in Azure ADF V2

Tags: azure, expression, azure-data-factory

I'm trying to use the expression @formatDateTime(dataset().WindowStartTime, 'hh') as a dynamic filename in Azure Data Factory V2.

I'm having the issue that when I'm using the value 2018-12-31T13:00:04.279Z for WindowStartTime, I'm expecting a filename of 13 but I'm getting a filename of 01.

I'm wondering what I need to do in the expression to get the time in 24 hour time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that changing `hh` to `HH` should solve your problem.

Take a look at [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings) for more information on custom formatting.

Hope it helps!